# Create tree structure without any parent as input from object list with one level

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree

I have a list of objects which contain a level. The order of the objects are referencing to the parent objects. The problem is, I don't have an parentId on my input data.

Input Data:

```
const listData = [
    { level: 1, name: "a" }, 
    { level: 2, name: "b", someOther: "asd" },
    { level: 2, name: "c" },
    { level: 3, name: "d" },
    { level: 4, name: "e" },
    { level: 2, name: "f" }
]
```

The output interface should look like this:

```
interface Item {
    name: String;
    listData?: Item[]
    ... otherKeys
}
```

I tried to add a parent reference to each object and a getParentByLevelsBackwards(element, levels), which did not really work out.

I have added a full test code here. Maybe someone has a good reference on solving such a problem or even better a working implementation for this problem?

```
// listData has n objects with n levels from 1 to x
// listData elements can have other attributes that should be persisted
// sublevel level should always +1
const assert = require("assert");

const listData = [{
        level: 1,
        name: "a"
    }, //first is always level 1
    {
        level: 2,
        name: "b",
        someOther: "asd"
    },
    {
        level: 2,
        name: "c"
    },
    {
        level: 3,
        name: "d"
    },
    {
        level: 4,
        name: "e"
    },
    // { level: 5, name: "e" }, // would give bonus points
    {
        level: 2,
        name: "f"
    }
];

const resultToBe = [{
    level: 1,
    name: "a",
    listData: [{
            level: 2,
            name: "b",
            someOther: "asd"
        },
        {
            level: 2,
            name: "c",
            listData: [{
                level: 3,
                name: "d",
                listData: [{
                    level: 4,
                    name: "e"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            level: 2,
            name: "f"
        }
    ]
}];

const createResult = listData => {
    return [];
};

const test = () => {
    const result = createResult(listData);
    console.log("Input is:", JSON.stringify(listData, null, 4));
    console.log("Result is:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    assert.deepStrictEqual(result, resultToBe, "Objects missmatch");
};

test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array for the levels as helper array for the last inserted levels.

```js
const
    listData = [{ level: 1, name: "a" }, { level: 2, name: "b", someOther: "asd" }, { level: 2, name: "c" }, { level: 3, name: "d" }, { level: 4, name: "e" }, { level: 2, name: "f" }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

listData.forEach(o => {
    o.children = [];
    levels[o.level] = o.children;
    levels[o.level - 1].push(o);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same without empty children arrays.

```js
const
    listData = [{ level: 1, name: "a" }, { level: 2, name: "b", someOther: "asd" }, { level: 2, name: "c" }, { level: 3, name: "d" }, { level: 4, name: "e" }, { level: 2, name: "f" }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

listData.forEach(o => {
    if (!levels[o.level - 1]) {
        var temp = levels[o.level - 2],
            last = temp[temp.length - 1];
        levels[o.level - 1] = [];
        last.children = levels[o.level - 1];
    }
    levels[o.level - 1].push(o);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```